# How do I store documents with multikey Id using GridStore?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I'm using GridStore, and I want to store a document with Id that has multiple keys.

I tried this:

```
var gridStore = new GridStore(db, {uuid: uuid, format: fileName}, 'w');

// Open the file
gridStore.open(function (err, gridStore) {
    // Write some data to the file
    gridStore.write(data, function (err, gridStore) {
        assert.equal(null, err);

        // Close (Flushes the data to MongoDB)
        gridStore.close(function (err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);

            // Verify that the file exists
            GridStore.exist(db, {uuid: uuid, format: fileName}, 
                function (err, result) {
                    assert.equal(null, err);
                    assert.equal(true, result);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

But it failed because the `assert.equal(true, result);` statement.

How do I store documents with multikey Id using GridStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should supply a filename to GridStore constructor and it will work:

```
var gridStore = new GridStore(db, {uuid: uuid, format: fileName}, 'foobar', 'w');
```

I dug through GridStore [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/1.4/lib/mongodb/gridfs/gridstore.js#L7) on GitHub and found this piece of code (only relevant parts are displayed):

```
if(typeof mode === 'undefined') {
  mode = filename;
  filename = undefined;
}

if(id instanceof ObjectID) {
  this.referenceBy = REFERENCE_BY_ID;
  this.fileId = id;
  this.filename = filename;
} else if(typeof filename == 'undefined') {
  this.referenceBy = REFERENCE_BY_FILENAME;
  this.filename = id;
  if (mode.indexOf('w') != null) {
    this.fileId = new ObjectID();
  }
} else {
  this.referenceBy = REFERENCE_BY_ID;
  this.fileId = id;
  this.filename = filename;
}
```

So basically, if you don't supply the `filename` option GridStore will reference the documents by filename and a new ObjectId for the `_id` field will be created. If you supply the filename option the `_id` will be the one you specified.

You can also verify this by inspecting `fs.files` collection and checking the `_id` value for your files.